# Stack with Array

Tags: java, array, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

Just coded up a simple Stack using an Array in Java for practice. Other than the lack of JavaDoc (still need to learn that part), did I cover all the bases?

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ArrayStack<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private T[] stack;
    private int top = 0;  //Position of the top of the stack

    //Constructor
    public ArrayStack(int size) {
        //Generic array creation isn't allowed, using cast
        stack = (T[]) new Object[size];
    } //End Constructor

    //Add item to top of stack
    public void push(T item) {
        //If you've reached top of stack, double it's size
        if (top == stack.length) {
            resize(stack.length *2);
        }

        stack[top++] = item;
        StdOut.println(stack[top-1] + " Added to stack"); //For debugging
    } //End push

    //Removes item from top of stack
    public T pop() {
            T toReturn = stack[--top];
            stack[top] = null;  //Garbage cleanup

            //Reduce size of array if it is less than 1/3rd full
            if (top < stack.length/3 && top > 10) {
                resize(stack.length/2);
            }
            return toReturn;
    } //End pop

    //Simple true or false if the stack is empty or not
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == 0);
    } //End isEmpty

    //Returns the iterator
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new StackIterator();
    } //End iterator

    public class StackIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        private int i = top; //Increment starting at top of stack

        @Override
        //True until i is the bottom of the stack
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (i > 0);
        } //End hasNext

        @Override
        //Returns the items in the stack starting from top
        public T next() {
            return stack[--i];
        } //End next

        @Override
        //Not implemented
        public void remove() { }
    } //End StackIterator

    //Creates a new array of the passed in size and copy values into it
    private void resize(int size) {
        StdOut.println("Resizing stack to " + size);  //For debugging
        //New array for values
        T[] tempStack = (T[]) new Object[size];

        //Copies values into new array
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            tempStack[i] = stack[i];  
        }
        //Assign stack to the new array
        stack = tempStack;
        StdOut.println("Stack size is now " + stack.length); //For debugging

    } //End resize

    //Test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 5;
        //Have to use wrapper Integer since it's expecting an object
        ArrayStack<Integer> myStack  = new ArrayStack<Integer>(size);  

        int choice = 3;
        while (choice != 0) {
            StdOut.println();
            StdOut.println("1: Push a number to top of stack");
            StdOut.println("2: Pop  a number from top of stack");
            StdOut.println("3: Display stack");
            StdOut.println("0: Quit");
            StdOut.print("Choice: ");
            choice = StdIn.readInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                StdOut.print("Number to add: ");
                Integer toAdd = StdIn.readInt();
                myStack.push(toAdd);
            }

            else if (choice == 2) {
                StdOut.println(myStack.pop() + " removed from stack");  
            }

            else if (choice == 3) {
                for (Integer x : myStack) {
                    StdOut.println(x + " ");
                }
            }
        } //End while
    } //End main
} //End ArrayStack
```

Comment: The contract of `Iterator` requires that `next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if it is empty. Throwing any other exception is just plain wrong, as that would be an unpleasent surprise for any client code relying on the documentation of `Iterator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, comment pairs such as `//Constructor ... //End Constructor` are redundant and actually makes the code a little harder to read.

Your debugging statements can be better served using a standard logging library that lets you log statements categorized by severity, e.g. [`org.slf4j.Logger.debug()`](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#debug%28java.lang.String%29).

Instead of creating your inner class `StackIterator`, you can consider in-lining the implementation in the following way:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>(){
        private int i = top; //Increment starting at top of stack

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            // suggested by @Landei and @AluanHadda
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return stack[--i];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}
```

You can also see that `remove()` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException()`, to make the (non-)usage more apparent.

Last but not least, I'm not sure how much `reinventing-the-wheel` do you intend/expect to do here, but you can also look into using [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-%5B%5D,%20int%29) to handle the array resizing.

Comment: This a good answer but there are few things I would add/change `1.` Regarding the anonymous`Iterator<T>` class, the key thing is that the implementation not be exposed, a private inner `StackItereator` class would do as well in this example. `2.` Growing the array by doubling it is standard practice, but shrinking it is probably worse for performance than leaving it as is. `3.` As @Landei noted `next` should throw `NoSuchElementException` if exhausted. `4.` The `println` calls are probably preferable to taking a dependency on slf4j for a practice example, but consider overriding `toString`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for the suggestions! I've updated the code snippet slightly to include your third point. :)